# How do you make a button return a boolean value?

Tags: android, button, boolean, handler, runnable

I am trying to make a stop watch application that when you press start it starts and when you press stop it stops. I am using a handler and runnable with post delay, but I want it to only post if the Stop button has not been pressed. This is the way I am talking about implementing what I am talking about.

```
if(!StopBClicked()){
     handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

This is what I have so far for making it a boolean thing.

```
public boolean StopBClicked() {
    Button StopB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StopB);
    StopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

But as you might guess it doesn't work. It is giving me an error at the ")" after OnClickListener(. I am a little new so I would appreciate a example code. Thank you.

Comment: You don't. Really. It makes so sense -- what would get the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run your action when the button is clicked.

Add this to your `onCreate`:

```
Button StopB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StopB);
StopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Android UI is [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) programming.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done any Android dev, but I would presume it's a syntax error. Assuming it's not a copy error made by the StackOverflow editor pasting some code, shouldn't it be:

```
private boolean StopBClicked() {
    Button StopB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StopB);
    StopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Well this gives an error saying that View.OnClickListener() is unimplemented. Usually it is implemented by public void onClick(){}